# "付け消しボタン"で消したときだけ、"サイズ切り替えボタン"を機能しなくする方法

Tags: javascript, html

アナログ時計を消しているとき(KILL(切る))、"サイズの切り替えボタン"を押すと、
水面下で切り替えが行われていたので、下記のソースのように"continue"を使って
みました。
そうしましたところ、アナログ時計を出した１回目は、サイズの切り替えが繰り返し
できますが、消してからもう一度出すと、サイズの切り替えができなくなります。
"付け消しボタン"で*消したときだけ*、"サイズ切り替えボタン"を*機能しなくする*には、
どうすればいいでしょうか？

なお、追加した文は、
document.getElementById('tog1').onclick="continue";
です。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis"> 

<TITLE>妖怪クロック(アナログ) - JavaScript</TITLE>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.butt{
BACKGROUND:maroon; 
COLOR:gold;
}
//-->
</style>


<BODY bgcolor="black" text="white">

<div id="clock" style="visibility:hidden">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

// 状態変数
var scale = 1;
var transitionStarted = 0;
var transitionFrom = 0;
var transitionTo = 0;
var transitionDuration = 0;

// サイズの変更を開始する処理
function toBigger(){
{
    transitionStarted = new Date().getTime();
    transitionFrom = scale;
    transitionTo = 3; // 最終的な倍率。状態により変化
    transitionDuration = 1000;
document.getElementById("tog1").value= " ORIGINAL ";
}
if(transitionFrom==3){
    transitionTo =  1; // 最終的な倍率。状態により変化
    transitionDuration = 1000;
document.getElementById("tog1").value= "＼BiGGER／";
}
}

(function(){
    "use strict";

function $(sel)
{
    return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel)
{
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined')
    {
        return document.getElementsByName(sel);
    }
    return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

var dCol = '', //date colour.
    sCol = '', //seconds colour.
    mCol = '', //minutes colour.
    hCol = '', //hours colour.
    fCol = '', //face color

    ClockHeight = 50,
    ClockWidth = 50,
    ClockFromMouseY = 0,
    ClockFromMouseX = 100,
    d = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    date = new Date(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    year = date.getYear() + 1900;
var TodaysDate = " " + d[date.getDay()] + " " + day + " " + m[date.getMonth()] + " " + year;
var D = TodaysDate.split('');
var H = '☆☆☆';
    H = H.split('');
var M = '☆☆☆☆';
    M = M.split('');
var S = '・・・・・';
    S = S.split('');
var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
    font = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    size = 1,
    speed = 0.45;
    Face = Face.split(' ');
var n = Face.length;
var a = size * 10;
var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0,
    scrll = 0,
    props = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + fCol + '">',
    props2 = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + dCol + '">';
var Split = 360 / n;
var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;
var HandHeight = ClockHeight / 4.5; 
var HandWidth = ClockWidth / 4.5;
var HandY = -7,
    HandX = -2.5,
    step = 0.02,
    currStep = 0,
    y = [],
    x = [],
    Y = [],
    X = [],
    Dy = [],
    Dx = [],
    DY = [],
    DX = [];
var i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    y[i] = 0;
    x[i] = 0;
    Y[i] = 0;
    X[i] = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) 
{
    Dy[i] = 0;
    Dx[i] = 0;
    DY[i] = 0;
    DX[i] = 0;
}
var wrapper = $('clock');
var html = '';
// Date wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Face wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    html += '<div class="Face" name="Face" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props + Face[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Hours wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Hours" name="Hours" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + hCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + H[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Minute wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Minutes" name="Minutes" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + mCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + M[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Seconds wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Seconds" name="Seconds" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + sCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + S[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Mouse move event handler

function Mouse(evnt) 
{
    if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')
    {
        ymouse = event.Y + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = event.X + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
    else
    {
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
}

document.onmousemove = Mouse;

function ClockAndAssign() 
{
    var time = new Date();

    // 状態変更処理
    if(transitionStarted)
    {
        var d = time.getTime() - transitionStarted;
        if (d < transitionDuration)
        {
            scale = transitionFrom + (transitionTo - transitionFrom) * d / transitionDuration;
        }
        else
        {
            // トランジション終了
            scale = transitionTo;
            transitionStarted = 0;
        }
    }

    var secs = time.getSeconds();
    var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
    var mins = time.getMinutes();
    var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
    var hr = time.getHours();
    var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(time.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
    $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var F = $$('Face')[i];
        F.style.top = y[i] + scale * ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        F.style.left = x[i] + scale * ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        var HL = $$('Hours')[i];
        HL.style.top = y[i] + HandY + scale * (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll;
        HL.style.left = x[i] + HandX + scale * (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(hrs);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
    {
        var ML = $$('Minutes')[i].style;
        ML.top = y[i] + HandY + scale * (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(min) + scrll;
        ML.left = x[i] + HandX + scale * (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(min);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
    {
        var SL = $$('Seconds')[i].style;
        SL.top = y[i] + HandY + scale * (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll;
        SL.left = x[i] + HandX + scale * (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(sec);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
    {
        var DL = $$('Date')[i].style;
        DL.top = Dy[i] + scale * ClockHeight * 1.5 * Math.sin(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        DL.left = Dx[i] + scale * ClockWidth * 1.5 * Math.cos(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    currStep -= step;
}

function Delay() 
{
    scrll = 0;
    Dy[0] = Math.round(DY[0] += ((ymouse) - DY[0]) * speed);
    Dx[0] = Math.round(DX[0] += ((xmouse) - DX[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
        Dy[i] = Math.round(DY[i] += (Dy[i - 1] - DY[i]) * speed);
        Dx[i] = Math.round(DX[i] += (Dx[i - 1] - DX[i]) * speed);
    }
    y[0] = Math.round(Y[0] += ((ymouse) - Y[0]) * speed);
    x[0] = Math.round(X[0] += ((xmouse) - X[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.round(Y[i] += (y[i - 1] - Y[i]) * speed);
        x[i] = Math.round(X[i] += (x[i - 1] - X[i]) * speed);
    }
    ClockAndAssign();
    setTimeout(Delay, 20);
}

Delay();

}());

num = 1;
function toggle(){
 num ^= 1; 
 if(num == 1){ 
document.getElementById('Od').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Of').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Oh').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Om').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('Os').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('tog1').onclick='continue';
 }
else { 
document.getElementById('Od').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Of').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Oh').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Om').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('Os').style.visibility="visible";
} 
document.getElementById("tog").value = num ?" APPEAR ":"KILL(切る)";
}
//--->
</script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center><p>
<input class="butt" id="tog" type="button"  value="今何時？" onclick="toggle()">
<input class="butt" id="tog1"  type="button" value="＼BIGGER／" onclick="toBigger()">
</p></center>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

機能させないために`.onclick='continue'`していますが、(`.onclick=null`の方がいいかと思います。）
`else`で無効にした関数を設定し直す必要があると思います。
以下は例

```
if(num == 1){ 
    document.getElementById('Od').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById('Of').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById('Oh').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById('Om').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById('Os').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById('tog1').onclick=null;
} else { 
    document.getElementById('Od').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('Of').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('Oh').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('Om').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('Os').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('tog1').onclick=toBigger;
}
```

---

後、質問とは直接関係ないですが、非表示と表示は親の要素でできますので、
以下の様に書けます。

```
if(num == 1){
    document.getElementById('clock').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById('tog1').onclick=null;
} else {
    document.getElementById('clock').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('tog1').onclick=toBigger;
}
```

Comment: 回等ありがとうございました。
まだ、言葉の定義が飲み込めていませんので、精確に使いこなせないで
います。"null"を使うとは、思いもつきませんでした。

"clock"を親要素として使っていましたが、なぜかうまくいかなかったので、
変だなと思っていたのです。再度使って見ましたら、うまくいきました。

それにしても専門家がやると、贅肉を削ぎ取り、スリムになるものですね。
驚きの連続です！

Comment: @user9359  強制ではありませんが、この回答で解決したのであれば[回答の承認](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)をして下さい。[参考](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)